# What does a "Full" server mean?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have a friend who played Star Wars: The Old Republic during the prerelease window.  His characters are on one of the really early servers.

Now that the game has been released and other people are joining up, we of course want to play together.  However, I noticed that the early server in question is now "Full." I understand that this means there are lots of people on the server, but I don't know in detail what this might mean.

Some questions:

- What kind of queue times can we expect when attempting to log in to a Full server?
- Are we in any danger of being locked out from that server (IE prevented from creating characters on it)?
- Is there any way for my friend to move his characters *off* the server if we decide we'd rather go to a less populated one after all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full is a term they use to mean that the population is very high and will likely create queue times during peak hours.

> What kind of queue times can we expect when attempting to log in to a Full server?

This is hard to answer since its very server dependent I've seen servers in full status go in queue from 10 mins to 2 hours. So for this you may need to monitor it some to see how "full" the server is during peak hours and your play times. A lot of times during off or non peak hours there is no waits.

> Are we in any danger of being locked out from that server (IE prevented from creating characters on it)?

I have not seen any information stating they would lock out any servers at all based on population, and it would need to get very very bad before i see this happening or even being considered, as they don't want to break up groups.

> Is there any way for my friend to move his characters off the server if we decide we'd rather go to a less populated one after all?

Currently right now no there is not. In the future I'd expect them to offer this service, though most likely it will be a paid service as most other MMOs offer.

Source: I have played in the beta, pre-release and release.

Comment: Here is a recent official statment about serverpopulation: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=60893

Comment: Also, the game is still new. Before you panic, give it a little time for the "newness" (and the 30 day time included with the key) to wear off and only the people who enjoy the game enough to pay the monthly fee will be around. If at that time servers are still overpopulated, expect more servers to open up to alleviate the server stress.

Comment: @Adanion I was mostly concerned with being locked out or having several-hour queue times during the important first few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions in point:

- It depends on what point in the queue you are at when you try to log in, it can be as short as 30 seconds, it can be as long as 15 minutes.
- No you are not going to be locked out, you can create other characters on that server. (I don't know if there is a character limit based on your account).
- Presently there is no way to move a character off a server. You will have to create a new one with present setups.